What does that Fire +1 and Arcane +1 mean?
I would like to know how/when that +1 affects the game.
I already used a Fire and an Arcane card and nothing changed.
I can't find where in the game those properties come into play.


After playing for a few days I finally understand the game!
This game is about the "synergy" of the cards.
For instance, in the print screen in the question, the Talented property is Fire+1. That doesn't mean initially anything for the Apprentice, since none of his cards are Fire. They are all "Apprentice" cards.
But, let us say he finds a Leather-bound Tome:

That tome is Fire +1, right? So the cards my character will gain are Fire1 and Fire2 (Fire1 because of the Fire+1 of the card and Fire2 because of the +1 of the trait):

